# Capistrano 3.2 could not fetch origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano3

I've got a rails 3.2 app which has been using capistrano v2 to deploy to my staging & production servers happily for a year. Now I'm trying to upgrade to capistrano v3 and I'm getting this issue;

```
INFO[2f0d4d3d] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update on staging.pais.com.au
DEBUG[2f0d4d3d] Command: cd /srv/pais/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/pais/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git remote update )
DEBUG[2f0d4d3d]     Fetching origin
DEBUG[2f0d4d3d]     Fetching origin
DEBUG[2f0d4d3d]     error: Could not fetch origin
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host staging.pais.com.au: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: error: Could not fetch origin
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `block (5 levels) in _execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `block (3 levels) in _execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:172:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:186:in `with_ssh'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/git.rb:11:in `git'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/git.rb:29:in `update'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:53:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:51:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: error: Could not fetch origin
```

Here is my deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, "pais"

# Version control system 
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url,  "map7@192.168.200.4:/home/map7/pais"
set :branch, "master"
set :git_enable_submodules, 1   # Get submodules
set :git_submodules_recursive, true

# Remote user info
set :user, "map7"     # 'vps' is the default MammothVPS user
set :use_sudo, false

# RBENV setup
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.1.1"
set :rbenv_path, "/usr/local/rbenv"
bundle_path = "/usr/local/rbenv/shims/bundle"

# Setup stages
set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "staging"

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
set :deploy_to, "/srv/pais" 

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my deploy/staging.rb

```
server 'staging.pais.com.au', user: 'map7', roles: %w{web app db}, :primary => true
```

It is creating the /srv/pais/repo directory and it has an origin set. I can ssh from the staging server to my development machine without a password using keys.

Comment: ssh as the same user that it's trying to deploy as?

Comment: All ssh tests and deploy is done by my user 'map7'

Answer (score 1):

This line `error: Could not fetch origin` points me to an issue connecting to your git repo.

The git URL from your `deploy.rb` should end with `.git`. So, something like:

`set :repo_url,  "map7@192.168.200.4:/home/map7/pais.git"`

Also, double check that the rest of the path to your git repo is correct, and that you have indeed ssh access to your server hosting the git repo.